# Laravel queries: Get all vehicles without bookings in specific date range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

These are my `vehicle` and `booking` models:

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    ....
    public function vehicle(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vehicle', 'vehicle_id');
    }
    ....
}

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    ....
    public function bookings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Booking', 'vehicle_id');
    }
    ....
}
```

In my controller I want to get all the vehicles that don't have bookings in given dates, so this is what I have tried so far:

```
public function availabillity(Request $request){

        $bookings = Booking::query();
        $vehicles = Vehicle::query();

        $selectedStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['start']); 
        $selectedEnd =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['end']);
        //$availableVehicles = [];

        $availableVehicles = $vehicles->select('vehicles.id')->leftjoin('bookings', function ($join) use ($selectedStart, $selectedEnd){
            $join->on('vehicles.id', '=', 'bookings.vehicle_id')
                ->where([
                        ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedStart], //selected start is between booking dates
                        ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedStart]
                    ])->orWhere([
                        ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedEnd],   //selected end is between boking dates
                        ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedEnd]
                    ])->orWhere([
                        ['bookings.start', '>',$selectedStart],  //booking dates are between selected start and selected end
                        ['bookings.end', '<', $selectedEnd]
                    ]);
            })->distinct('vehicles.id')->get();


       $res = [];
       $res['vehicles'] = $availableVehicles;
       $res['selected_start'] = $selectedStart ;
       $res['selected_end'] = $selectedEnd;

       return response($res);


    }
```

But it doesn't work. I still get all cars even though I have a booking with:

```
start: 2020-02-05 11:40:00
end:   2020-02-10 12:40:00
```

and my request is for dates:

```
start: 2020-02-05 12:01:00
end:   2020-02-12 12:00:00
```

How I can modify my query in order to get available vehicles? Is there a more efficient way instead of a complex query? Maybe by altering my models?

**EDIT**

These are my tables:

Bookings:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | start               | end                 | vehicle_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| 29 | 2020-02-05 11:40:00 | 2020-02-10 12:40:00 | 38         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Vehicles

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 37 |
+----+
| 38 |
+----+
| 39 |
+----+
| 40 |
+----+
```

So based in the input dates I would expect to get:

```
37,39,40
```

Instead I get all vehicle ids

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Comment: @Strawberry any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I added the tables and expected result...

Comment: One row is rarely enough to be representative. And it helps if you actually follow the instructions suggested.

Comment: @Strawberry nevermind for someone one row was representative and helped me solve the issue.

Comment: Good. Just to note, that solution includes more code than is strictly necessary. In general, Events A and B overlap id Event B starts before Event A ends, and ends after Event A starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function availabillity(Request $request){

    $selectedStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['start']); 
    $selectedEnd =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request['end']);
    //$availableVehicles = [];

    $availableVehicles = $vehicles->whereDoesntHave('bookings', function($query) use ($selectedStart, $selectedEnd) {
        $query->where([
                    ['bookings.start', '<',$selectedEnd], 
                    ['bookings.end', '>', $selectedStart]
                ]);
    })->get();


   $res = [];
   $res['vehicles'] = $availableVehicles;
   $res['selected_start'] = $selectedStart ;
   $res['selected_end'] = $selectedEnd;

   return response($res);


}
```

Comment: ErrorException: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in file

Comment: add `[  ]` to `doesntHave(['bookings' => function])`

Comment: I changed with whereDoesntHave and I dont get any error. But I still get all the cars

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are using `orWhere`, it will return every row accomplishing one of the conditions, which happens to be all of them.

Change `orWhere` for `where` and it will use 'and' instead of 'or' and it should work.

Comment: But I am using a left join. So I want all rows that don't accomplish any of the conditions. Thats why I used `OR` . I tried with `where` but I still get the same results though.

Comment: Then you should use the opposites of the conditions ie changing every > for < and vice versa and use where instead of orwhere

Comment: But then it won't be a left join I guess